# XmlSerializer and complex prefixes

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xmlserializer, prefix

I'm trying to work out how to produce some Xml which has more than trivial use of prefixes from a set of classes with XmlSerializer.  I also want to be able to read in the same Xml (which is reasonably  straightforward but seems to dissapear as I use more complex attributes.

The specific use case is the opf file from an ebook.

here is an example of the Xml I want to produce

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="uuid_id">
  <metadata xmlns:xsi=""dchttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:calibre="http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:publisher>Baen Publishing Enterprises</dc:publisher>
    <meta name = "calibre:series_index" content="1"/>
    <dc:rights>2002 by Lois McMaster Bujold.</dc:rights>
    <dc:language>en-us</dc:language>
    <dc:creator opf:file-as="Bujold., Lois McMaster " opf:role= "aut" > Lois McMaster Bujold.</dc:creator>
    <meta name = "calibre:timestamp" content= "2010-05-07T17:42:06.859000+00:00" />
    <dc:title>Miles Errant</dc:title>
    <meta name = "cover" content= "RW_0743435583_Cover" />
    <dc:date>2002-09-01T04:00:00+00:00</dc:date>
    <dc:contributor opf:role= "bkp" > calibre(0.6.51)[http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net]</dc:contributor>
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme = "ISBN" > 0 - 7434 - 3558 - 3 </dc:identifier >
    <dc:identifier id = "uuid_id" opf:scheme = "uuid" > c7e276b6 - 1a12 - 4130 - a7ac - b2febb9730fb </dc:identifier >
    <dc:subject > Science Fiction </dc:subject >
  </metadata > 
</package>
```

The classes corresponding look like this:-

```
public class package
{
    public metadata metadata { get; set; }
}

public class metadata
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string language { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string creator { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string rights { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public List<identifier> identifier { get; set; }
}

public class identifier
{
    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf")]
    public string scheme { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

and the writing code (currently) is

```
    public static Stream WriteToStream(package p)
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
        namespaces.Add("", "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf");
        XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(package));


        Stream s = new MemoryStream();
        serialiser.Serialize(s, p, namespaces);
        s.Position = 0;
        return s;
    }
```

this produces the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <title xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Miles Errant</title>
    <language xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">en-us</language>
    <creator xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> Lois McMaster Bujold.</creator>
    <publisher xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Baen Publishing Enterprises</publisher>
    <rights xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2002 by Lois McMaster Bujold.</rights>
    <identifier d3p1:scheme="ISBN" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> 0 - 7434 - 3558 - 3 </identifier>
    <identifier id="uuid_id" d3p1:scheme="uuid" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> c7e276b6 - 1a12 - 4130 - a7ac - b2febb9730fb </identifier>
    </metadata>
  <manifest />
</package>
```

if I add the dc namespace to the root element then I get the dc prefix, however I can longer deserialize the sample.

If this is more complex than XmlSerializer is meant to handle then I can write the file manually, but I'd rather do it through markup than code.

Apologies for the long post.

Many thanks.

Iain

Comment: that "The classes corresponding look like this:" doesn't look right to me - surely you need `[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf")]` *at a minimum*? Have you tried auto-generating the types from the xml? (paste/special)

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like the confusion here is simply the namespaces on the first two elements; locally, I have:

```
[XmlRoot("package", Namespace = "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf")]
public class Package
{
    [XmlElement("metadata", Namespace = "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf")]
    public PackageMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

which now serializes and deserializes correctly.

Comment: Thankyou. That seems a significant improvement.  It doesn't give me quite the same structure as the original.  In particular the dc namespace is on the package and not the metadata.  I can see that that makes no difference in this context, but I imagine that if 'dc' had different meanings in different parts of the xml, I would need an approach other than XmlSerializer to produce the correct format.

Comment: @user1812615 "dc" is not a namespace - it is an *alias*; it is *you* that has defined the alias, but : the same *namespace* can be written with arbitrary aliases - it means exactly the same thing no matter whether it is `dc:Foo` or `blap:Foo`, as long as `xmlns:dc` and `xmlnd:blap` are equivalent. No xml parser cares about the alias - they only care about the *namespace*. So: this data is identical. The "difference" here is where the alias is declared; `XmlSerializer` does this at the root, but: that doesn't matter at all. Basically: there isn't a problem here - the data is identical.